# Xcode 6 Launch Screen issue

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode6

In xcode 6 when using launchScreen.xib as launch screen, my iPhone app is not running in 2x mode on iPad, how to solve the issue? how to launch iPhone app in iPad in 2x mode using launchScreen.xib as Launch screen?

Comment: i really need answer quickly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select Launch Screen, and in the options on right side, uncheck **"Use as Launch Screen"** option, I got it working this way

Comment: thanks, BTW i got solution, u can either use launchScreen.xib or launch images, By using launch images i able to run my iphone app in 2x mode on ipad.